# Mongoose update document in the moment of finding it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a query of tasks. When a task is requested, I am returning the oldest one with the following code:

```
Task.find({})
        // Filter for those that are not started yet
        .where('startDate').equals(null)
        // Sort ascending to get the oldest
        .sort({ reqDate: 'asc' }).findOne(function (err, task) { ... }
```

Inside of the final brackets, I set the *startDate* to the current time.
The requests are done by calling a single NodeJS (Express) API running express and communicating with MongoDB by using Mongoose.

This works well with just one person requesting tasks, but I am thinking of a huge scale right now. What if there are multiple people requesting in the same moment, all receiving the same task as they come in in the same timespan of a few milliseconds?

Is there a way to make sure that the `startDate` of the document is set in the moment it is found by mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mongo there's `db.collection.findAndModify()` and `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()`:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

But you are likely to get race conditions anyway. You may be better off implementing your queues with Redis, RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, ActiveMQ, NSQ etc.

See:

- https://redis.io/
- https://www.rabbitmq.com/
- http://zeromq.org/
- http://activemq.apache.org/
- http://nsq.io/

Much more tools are here:

- http://queues.io/

To sum it up, you may be able to work around your current problem with `db.collection.findAndModify()` and `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()` but using a proper tool for queues or pub/sub will save you a lot of trouble, especially when you start processing multiple tasks concurrently.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I need. Will definitly take a closer look into your suggestions aswell.